# Using .htaccess mod_rewrite to insert a script name at the start of the path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with an htaccess url rewrite, that works fine at localhost but doesn't work on my hosting (anhosting).

I need to redirect all the request to my index.php page.
Here's an example: i would to redirect

```
http://mydomain.com/this/is/a/page
```

to

```
http://mydomain.com/index.php/this/is/a/page
```

This is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

on the hosting i always get redirected to the index.php file, but the $1 parameters results always blank, so my custom framework cannot handle the request correctly.

What could be the problem?

Sorry for my bad english, i hope i have been clear enough...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the remote server has [`AcceptPathInfo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html) turned off. That setting is responsible for the effect you are using.

Try a manual request to

```
http://mydomain.com/index.php/this/is/a/page
```

if `this/is/a/page` vanishes, then that option is definitely turned off, and you can't use this method on the remote server (unless you can change its configuration).

In that case, I would change the rule to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and change the framework to listen for `$_GET["path"]` instead of `$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]`.

Comment: http://mydomain.com/index.php/this/is/a/page <- this works... i definitely think that the problem is someway related to mod_rewrite...

Comment: Luciano can you try `%1` instead of `$1`?

Comment: I've just tried to use the `R` flag and i added a slash (`/`) before the `index.php` and the redirect seems to work... but it still doesn't seem to work without the hard redirect...

Comment: I worked for few hours with an ANHosting technician and we were able to make it work using the $_GET['q'] alternative but sadly we still couldn't be able to use $_REQUEST['PATH_INFO'] ...

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the mod-rewrite in the Apache configuration files.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
```

Here's a site that shows you a few ways. I have done my mod-rewrites by modifying the above files but I think there are other ways.

http://drupal.org/node/134439

Comment: Unfortunately i have not the full access on the server (i'm on a shared hosting and i can just use Cpanel...) I talked with anhosting and they assured me that mod_rewrite is enabled... they also installed a "REALLY" simple demo on my webspace to show me that's really enabled... when i asked about this problem they said me that this kind of request are not of their competence...